# C++/QT: "run" a QAction

Tags: c++, qt

I need to automate a gui test using qt,c++,qtest (in eclipse)
I have a dynamically created menu with dynamically created QActions, from which I need to test a "new tab" QAction (inside the menu), this is how he is created:

```
  m_pNewTabAction = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/add.png"), tr("&New Tab"), this);
  m_pNewTabAction->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+N"));
  m_pNewTabAction->setStatusTip(tr("Open a new tab"));
  connect(m_pNewTabAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(NewTab()));
```

In my testclass, I managed to get access to the private QAction object (m_pNewTabAction) using  the "findChildren" function, now I dont know how I can "execute" the QAction (or in other words "add a new tab")
My testclass:

```
    //Get the actions available for the filemenu
    QList<QAction *> fileactions = filemenu->findChildren<QAction *>();
    //Execute an action??
    fileactions.front()-> //how do I execute my QAction?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`QAction::activate()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaction.html#activate):

```
void QAction::activate(ActionEvent event)
```

`ActionEvent` is one of `QAction::Trigger` or `QAction::Hover`. You probably want `QAction::Trigger`.

Comment: that's what I thought as well, but it didn't work: I tired trigger and hover but that function "NewTab()" does not seem to be called anytime or in other words: there's no new tab comming up

Comment: @RandomDisplayName That must be a different problem, then, in code which you're not showing. The Qt docs of [`triggered()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) explicitly state that it's called when `activate(Trigger)` is called. As a sanity check, does the tab appear when the action is user-triggered?

Comment: my biggest fear just came true ._. thanks for your help anyway I will accept your answer since it does technically answer the question, but the code is too big to show here

Comment: @RandomDisplayName Are you sure you are triggering the correct action? Perhaps you should create a method that returns your desired `QAction` object instead of using `findChildren` method.

Comment: I have to test 5 QActions in that filemenu, and findchildren gives back 5 objects, from which I can take any and test, but none of them work, so I guess as Angew mentioned, its another problem

Answer (score 1):

If the list of menu items is dynamically populated, you'll probably want to call setObjectName() on any item you need to look up with findChild() or findChildren(). Add this:

```
m_pNewTabAction->setObjectName("NewTabAction");
```

(The string doesn't need a tr() since it's internal only.) Then in your test, use findChild() and then call [QAction::trigger()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaction.html#trigger):

```
QVERIFY( filemenu );
QAction* action = filemenu->findChild<QAction*>( "NewTabAction" );
// OR you could look it up from the main window if the names are unique: 
//    QAction* action = mainWindow->findChild<QAction*>( "NewTabAction" );
QVERIFY( action );
action->trigger();
```

Comment: this does not change much, I mean I now get a QAction with a correct object name, but this does not solve the problem that trigger(); doesn't work. It must be somewhere else in the code as Angew mentioned before.

Comment: This ought to work, so you have some other problem if it doesn't. I added a couple QVERIFY() calls that may help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: +1 for findChild clarification, I solved it another way now (soulution does not have anything in common with my question so I wont post it), thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Run QAction from code, part my code ...

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonExit_clicked()
{        
    quitAction = new QAction(this);
    connect(quitAction, &QAction::triggered, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit);
    quitAction->trigger();
}
```